# Status code: 422 (error: {type: 'validation', message: 'Invalid message'})

Tags: javascript, api, rest

I am trying to write the following curl post function with basic authentication in vanilla javascript.

```
curl -X POST \
  https://api.livechatinc.com/v3.3/agent/action/list_chats \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer <your_access_token>' \
  -d '{}'
```

This is my code in javascript.

```
    (async () => {
      const rawResponse = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(username+":"+password)
        },
        body: {
         "filters.group_ids" : "1",
         "limit" : 1
        }
      });
      const content = await rawResponse.json();
      
      console.log(content);
    })();
```

I keep getting this error "error:
message: "Invalid message"
type: "validation""

The curl method works perfectly in postman. I have read the documentation about this error and tried removing the content type header. It did not work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What does `btoa()` do?

Comment: Encodes and returns a BASE64 string.

Comment: As I understand you have to do the authorization with Bearer token `-H 'Authorization: Bearer <your_access_token>' \` but you are doing a basic token way `'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(username+":"+password)`. Have you read the api docs?